# Apple receipt_data sample

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, backend, receipt-validation

I need to implement a back-end for verifying Apple's in-app purchase *receipt_data*, for an in-app purchase of in-app points (i.e. not a subscription and not an item that needs to be "remembered" and re-verified in every application launch).

I am not proficient in iOS. I just need to develop the back-end so that it can be integrated with a client's mobile app.

I found tutorials and sample code for doing the verification, but I would very much like to have an actual *receipt_data* to test with.

The best thing would be to have two *receipt_data*s: one sandbox and one production.

I understand that there are two variations of *receipt_data*s I need to support - one that contains a single purchase's data, and another that contains the full history of purchases. If that's the case, it would be great to have a sample for each...

I realize that this is not a question per se, but maybe sample receipts would be useful for other developers as well...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a deprecated transaction (single transaction) style receipt:

```
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
```

And here is a Grand Unified Receipt (multiple transactions):

```
MIIcSAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIcOTCCHDUCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIL+QYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIIL6gSCC+YxggviMAoCAQgCAQEEAhYAMAoCARQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAQECAQEEAwIBADALAgEDAgEBBAMMATEwCwIBCwIBAQQDAgEAMAsCAQ4CAQEEAwIBWjALAgEPAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBEAIBAQQDAgEAMAsCARkCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgEKAgEBBAQWAjQrMA0CAQ0CAQEEBQIDAV+QMA0CARMCAQEEBQwDMS4wMA4CAQkCAQEEBgIEUDIzNDAYAgEEAgECBBDE3UBUsLYaB761hfaoQuBIMBsCAQACAQEEEwwRUHJvZHVjdGlvblNhbmRib3gwHAIBBQIBAQQULgoRW+rBxXAjpb03NJlVqa2Z200wHQIBAgIBAQQVDBNjb20ubWJhYXN5Lmlvcy5kZW1vMB4CAQwCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xM1QwNzo1MDo0NlowHgIBEgIBAQQWFhQyMDEzLTA4LTAxVDA3OjAwOjAwWjBLAgEHAgEBBEPixSwGknvYHA7GNo11ue/NJtHjgD6PTlcYOBGS4D+bAG3hIUBsvRx0RDoaF7CUW1XeUoKFE/jqIHH5AzsHl3pS/WYgMGECAQYCAQEEWRhf33g2yaZFPTmP34+a61oc/n3P7iVoZOuazq1x1u1JXgIDY2hJpxZU4y6o5FBZ8JZC+6uvjOlYYiOd9QfeqHBV4YwCU5Mbd5L2aJji1yJYTDmqHEroWyJ4MIIBTwIBEQIBAQSCAUUxggFBMAsCAgasAgEBBAIWADALAgIGrQIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrACAQEEAhYAMAsCAgayAgEBBAIMADALAgIGswIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga1AgEBBAIMADALAgIGtgIBAQQCDAAwDAICBqUCAQEEAwIBATAMAgIGqwIBAQQDAgEBMAwCAgauAgEBBAMCAQAwDAICBq8CAQEEAwIBADAMAgIGsQIBAQQDAgEAMBUCAgamAgEBBAwMCmNvbnN1bWFibGUwGwICBqcCAQEEEgwQMTAwMDAwMDE2Njg2NTIzMTAbAgIGqQIBAQQSDBAxMDAwMDAwMTY2ODY1MjMxMB8CAgaoAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMDdUMjA6Mzc6NTVaMB8CAgaqAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMDdUMjA6Mzc6NTVaMIIBZgIBEQIBAQSCAVwxggFYMAsCAgatAgEBBAIMADALAgIGsAIBAQQCFgAwCwICBrICAQEEAgwAMAsCAgazAgEBBAIMADALAgIGtAIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrUCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga2AgEBBAIMADAMAgIGpQIBAQQDAgEBMAwCAgarAgEBBAMCAQMwDAICBq4CAQEEAwIBADAMAgIGsQIBAQQDAgEAMBICAgamAgEBBAkMB21vbnRobHkwEgICBq8CAQEECQIHA41+ppRyaTAbAgIGpwIBAQQSDBAxMDAwMDAwMTY2OTY1MTUwMBsCAgapAgEBBBIMEDEwMDAwMDAxNjY5NjUxNTAwHwICBqgCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNjo0OTozMlowHwICBqoCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNjo0OTozM1owHwICBqwCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNjo1NDozMlowggFmAgERAgEBBIIBXDGCAVgwCwICBq0CAQEEAgwAMAsCAgawAgEBBAIWADALAgIGsgIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrMCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga0AgEBBAIMADALAgIGtQIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrYCAQEEAgwAMAwCAgalAgEBBAMCAQEwDAICBqsCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgIGrgIBAQQDAgEAMAwCAgaxAgEBBAMCAQAwEgICBqYCAQEECQwHbW9udGhseTASAgIGrwIBAQQJAgcDjX6mlHJqMBsCAganAgEBBBIMEDEwMDAwMDAxNjY5NjUzMjcwGwICBqkCAQEEEgwQMTAwMDAwMDE2Njk2NTE1MDAfAgIGqAIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA2OjU0OjMyWjAfAgIGqgIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA2OjUzOjE4WjAfAgIGrAIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA2OjU5OjMyWjCCAWYCARECAQEEggFcMYIBWDALAgIGrQIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrACAQEEAhYAMAsCAgayAgEBBAIMADALAgIGswIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga1AgEBBAIMADALAgIGtgIBAQQCDAAwDAICBqUCAQEEAwIBATAMAgIGqwIBAQQDAgEDMAwCAgauAgEBBAMCAQAwDAICBrECAQEEAwIBADASAgIGpgIBAQQJDAdtb250aGx5MBICAgavAgEBBAkCBwONfqaUcnUwGwICBqcCAQEEEgwQMTAwMDAwMDE2Njk2NTg5NTAbAgIGqQIBAQQSDBAxMDAwMDAwMTY2OTY1MTUwMB8CAgaoAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDY6NTk6MzJaMB8CAgaqAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDY6NTc6MzRaMB8CAgasAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDc6MDQ6MzJaMIIBZgIBEQIBAQSCAVwxggFYMAsCAgatAgEBBAIMADALAgIGsAIBAQQCFgAwCwICBrICAQEEAgwAMAsCAgazAgEBBAIMADALAgIGtAIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrUCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga2AgEBBAIMADAMAgIGpQIBAQQDAgEBMAwCAgarAgEBBAMCAQMwDAICBq4CAQEEAwIBADAMAgIGsQIBAQQDAgEAMBICAgamAgEBBAkMB21vbnRobHkwEgICBq8CAQEECQIHA41+ppRykDAbAgIGpwIBAQQSDBAxMDAwMDAwMTY2OTY3MTUyMBsCAgapAgEBBBIMEDEwMDAwMDAxNjY5NjUxNTAwHwICBqgCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNzowNDozMlowHwICBqoCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNzowMjozM1owHwICBqwCAQEEFhYUMjAxNS0wOC0xMFQwNzowOTozMlowggFmAgERAgEBBIIBXDGCAVgwCwICBq0CAQEEAgwAMAsCAgawAgEBBAIWADALAgIGsgIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrMCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga0AgEBBAIMADALAgIGtQIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrYCAQEEAgwAMAwCAgalAgEBBAMCAQEwDAICBqsCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgIGrgIBAQQDAgEAMAwCAgaxAgEBBAMCAQAwEgICBqYCAQEECQwHbW9udGhseTASAgIGrwIBAQQJAgcDjX6mlHKrMBsCAganAgEBBBIMEDEwMDAwMDAxNjY5Njc0ODQwGwICBqkCAQEEEgwQMTAwMDAwMDE2Njk2NTE1MDAfAgIGqAIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA3OjA5OjMyWjAfAgIGqgIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA3OjA4OjMwWjAfAgIGrAIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTA4LTEwVDA3OjE0OjMyWjCCAWYCARECAQEEggFcMYIBWDALAgIGrQIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrACAQEEAhYAMAsCAgayAgEBBAIMADALAgIGswIBAQQCDAAwCwICBrQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAga1AgEBBAIMADALAgIGtgIBAQQCDAAwDAICBqUCAQEEAwIBATAMAgIGqwIBAQQDAgEDMAwCAgauAgEBBAMCAQAwDAICBrECAQEEAwIBADASAgIGpgIBAQQJDAdtb250aGx5MBICAgavAgEBBAkCBwONfqaUcskwGwICBqcCAQEEEgwQMTAwMDAwMDE2Njk2Nzc4MjAbAgIGqQIBAQQSDBAxMDAwMDAwMTY2OTY1MTUwMB8CAgaoAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDc6MTQ6MzJaMB8CAgaqAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDc6MTI6MzRaMB8CAgasAgEBBBYWFDIwMTUtMDgtMTBUMDc6MTk6MzJaoIIOVTCCBWswggRToAMCAQICCBhZQyFydJz8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MB4XDTEwMTExMTIxNTgwMVoXDTE1MTExMTIxNTgwMVoweDEmMCQGA1UEAwwdTWFjIEFwcCBTdG9yZSBSZWNlaXB0IFNpZ25pbmcxLDAqBgNVBAsMI0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zMRMwEQYDVQQKDApBcHBsZSBJbmMuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALaTwrcPJF7t0jRI6IUF4zOUZlvoJze/e0NJ6/nJF5czczJJSshvaCkUuJSm9GVLO0fX0SxmS7iY2bz1ElHL5i+p9LOfHOgo/FLAgaLLVmKAWqKRrk5Aw30oLtfT7U3ZrYr78mdI7Ot5vQJtBFkY/4w3n4o38WL/u6IDUIcK1ZLghhFeI0b14SVjK6JqjLIQt5EjTZo/g0DyZAla942uVlzU9bRuAxsEXSwbrwCZF9el+0mRzuKhETFeGQHA2s5Qg17I60k7SRoq6uCfv9JGSZzYq6GDYWwPwfyzrZl1Kvwjm+8iCOt7WRQRn3M0Lea5OaY79+Y+7Mqm+6uvJt+PiIECAwEAAaOCAdgwggHUMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUiCcXCam2GGCL7Ou69kdZxVJUo7cwTQYDVR0fBEYwRDBCoECgPoY8aHR0cDovL2RldmVsb3Blci5hcHBsZS5jb20vY2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbmF1dGhvcml0eS93d2RyY2EuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUdXYkomtiDJc0ofpOXggMIr9z774wggERBgNVHSAEggEIMIIBBDCCAQAGCiqGSIb3Y2QFBgEwgfEwgcMGCCsGAQUFBwICMIG2DIGzUmVsaWFuY2Ugb24gdGhpcyBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBieSBhbnkgcGFydHkgYXNzdW1lcyBhY2NlcHRhbmNlIG9mIHRoZSB0aGVuIGFwcGxpY2FibGUgc3RhbmRhcmQgdGVybXMgYW5kIGNvbmRpdGlvbnMgb2YgdXNlLCBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBwb2xpY3kgYW5kIGNlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gcHJhY3RpY2Ugc3RhdGVtZW50cy4wKQYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuYXBwbGUuY29tL2FwcGxlY2EvMBAGCiqGSIb3Y2QGCwEEAgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCgO/GHvGm0t4N8GfSfxAJk3wLJjjFzyxw+3CYHi/2e8+2+Q9aNYS3k8NwWcwHWNKNpGXcUv7lYx1LJhgB/bGyAl6mZheh485oSp344OGTzBMtf8vZB+wclywIhcfNEP9Die2H3QuOrv3ds3SxQnICExaVvWFl6RjFBaLsTNUVCpIz6EdVLFvIyNd4fvNKZXcjmAjJZkOiNyznfIdrDdvt6NhoWGphMhRvmK0UtL1kaLcaa1maSo9I2UlCAIE0zyLKa1lNisWBS8PX3fRBQ5BK/vXG+tIDHbcRvWzk10ee33oEgJ444XIKHOnNgxNbxHKCpZkR+zgwomyN/rOzmoDvdMIIEIzCCAwugAwIBAgIBGTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBiMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UEChMKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEmMCQGA1UECxMdQXBwbGUgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkxFjAUBgNVBAMTDUFwcGxlIFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMDgwMjE0MTg1NjM1WhcNMTYwMjE0MTg1NjM1WjCBljELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoMCkFwcGxlIEluYy4xLDAqBgNVBAsMI0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zMUQwQgYDVQQDDDtBcHBsZSBXb3JsZHdpZGUgRGV2ZWxvcGVyIFJlbGF0aW9ucyBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMo4VKbLVqrIJDlI6Yzu7F+4fyaRvDRTes58Y4Bhd2RepQcjtjn+UC0VVlhwLX7EbsFKhT4v8N6EGqFXya97GP9q+hUSSRUIGayq2yoy7ZZjaFIVPYyK7L9rGJXgA6wBfZcFZ84OhZU3au0Jtq5nzVFkn8Zc0bxXbmc1gHY2pIeBbjiP2CsVTnsl2Fq/ToPBjdKT1RpxtWCcnTNOVfkSWAyGuBYNweV3RY1QSLorLeSUheHoxJ3GaKWwo/xnfnC6AllLd0KRObn1zeFM78A7SIym5SFd/Wpqu6cWNWDS5q3zRinJ6MOL6XnAamFnFbLw/eVovGJfbs+Z3e8bY/6SZasCAwEAAaOBrjCBqzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUiCcXCam2GGCL7Ou69kdZxVJUo7cwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUK9BpR5R2Cf70a40uQKb3R01/CF4wNgYDVR0fBC8wLTAroCmgJ4YlaHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBsZS5jb20vYXBwbGVjYS9yb290LmNybDAQBgoqhkiG92NkBgIBBAIFADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEA2jIAlsVUlNM7gjdmfS5o1cPGuMsmjEiQzxMkakaOY9Tw0BMG3djEwTcV8jMTOSYtzi5VQOMLA6/6EsLnDSG41YDPrCgvzi2zTq+GGQTG6VDdTClHECP8bLsbmGtIieFbnd5G2zWFNe8+0OJYSzj07XVaH1xwHVY5EuXhDRHkiSUGvdW0FY5e0FmXkOlLgeLfGK9EdB4ZoDpHzJEdOusjWv6lLZf3e7vWh0ZChetSPSayY6i0scqP9Mzis8hH4L+aWYP62phTKoL1fGUuldkzXfXtZcwxN8VaBOhr4eeIA0p1npsoy0pAiGVDdd3LOiUjxZ5X+C7O0qmSXnMuLyV1FTCCBLswggOjoAMCAQICAQIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkFwcGxlIEluYy4xJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFwcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BcHBsZSBSb290IENBMB4XDTA2MDQyNTIxNDAzNloXDTM1MDIwOTIxNDAzNlowYjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkFwcGxlIEluYy4xJjAkBgNVBAsTHUFwcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BcHBsZSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA5JGpCR+R2x5HUOsF7V55hC3rNqJXTFXsixmJ3vlLbPUHqyIwAugYPvhQCdN/QaiY+dHKZpwkaxHQo7vkGyrDH5WeegykR4tb1BY3M8vED03OFGnRyRly9V0O1X9fm/IlA7pVj01dDfFkNSMVSxVZHbOU9/acns9QusFYUGePCLQg98usLCBvcLY/ATCMt0PPD5098ytJKBrI/s61uQ7ZXhzWyz21Oq30Dw4AkguxIRYudNU8DdtiFqujcZJHU1XBry9Bs/j743DN5qNMRX4fTGtQlkGJxHRiCxCDQYczioGxMFjsWgQyjGizjx3eZXP/Z15lvEnYdp8zFGWhd5TJLQIDAQABo4IBejCCAXYwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFCvQaUeUdgn+9GuNLkCm90dNfwheMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFCvQaUeUdgn+9GuNLkCm90dNfwheMIIBEQYDVR0gBIIBCDCCAQQwggEABgkqhkiG92NkBQEwgfIwKgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmFwcGxlLmNvbS9hcHBsZWNhLzCBwwYIKwYBBQUHAgIwgbYagbNSZWxpYW5jZSBvbiB0aGlzIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIGJ5IGFueSBwYXJ0eSBhc3N1bWVzIGFjY2VwdGFuY2Ugb2YgdGhlIHRoZW4gYXBwbGljYWJsZSBzdGFuZGFyZCB0ZXJtcyBhbmQgY29uZGl0aW9ucyBvZiB1c2UsIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIHBvbGljeSBhbmQgY2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBwcmFjdGljZSBzdGF0ZW1lbnRzLjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAXDaZTC14t+2Mm9zzd5vydtJ3ME/BH4WDhRuZPUc38qmbQI4s1LGQEti+9HOb7tJkD8t5TzTYoj75eP9ryAfsfTmDi1Mg0zjEsb+aTwpr/yv8WacFCXwXQFYRHnTTt4sjO0ej1W8k4uvRt3DfD0XhJ8rxbXjt57UXF6jcfiI1yiXV2Q/Wa9SiJCMR96Gsj3OBYMYbWwkvkrL4REjwYDieFfU9JmcgijNq9w2Cz97roy/5U2pbZMBjM3f3OgcsVuvaDyEO2rpzGU+12TZ/wYdV2aeZuTJC+9jVcZ5+oVK3G72TQiQSKscPHbZNnF5jyEuAF1CqitXa5PzQCQc3sHV1ITGCAcswggHHAgEBMIGjMIGWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5AggYWUMhcnSc/DAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBAIa0+qXTtrEAb7a6j4vNufx2K9veaN6S7YJeS30EIaW6xpiwpz7gFz//uLk8NZkDN6fiFb+rAB00mI2CTX6lW3kGtUAAefg2tRFrJ0tpCdt5+03popovMb8KzDRqlJuKs6D6xzx+MSxKV6i7iPHHaxoq3eAFS2i9N6BwuH52vwSJ6+vUJsH+klw2sSCL/XAaLCpzQDS66V6CqbUo6peo/hqtHsOAjDmFgTNPXXVAPXMk+q3loe+oveSC4n362W7f+N6R9CB6lJ8rloluUN2JvNwiFzPY0eAtCToLpBfGdL2I3ymDFJWiQbCuuNRa/PfGBFpMc0PGSqyQ0C5GFULTDVU=
```

Both from sandbox (sorry can't give you any production ones). Enjoy.

**Edit:** It occurs to me that would won't be able to communicate to Apple's servers with these receipt without my shared secret (not something I am willing to disclose).

However you can decode them, if you're using ruby I wrote a gem called [ItunesReceiptDecoder](https://github.com/mbaasy/itunes_receipt_decoder). I also have a gem called [ItunesReceiptValidator](https://github.com/mbaasy/itunes_receipt_validator) that also provides the remote calls to Apple.

Comment: Please note that above sample uses expired certificates:
- Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
- Mac App Store Receipt Signing
so they won't pass e.g `openssl smime -verify` and this is normal.

Comment: Aware this is a *very* old question, but I don't suppose you know if these are base64 encoded? `Data(base64Encoded:)` in Swift doesn't seem to like them!

Comment: Hi, Marc! Do you have any links on the official documentation about two receipt formats: `ewo...` (single transaction) and `MII...` (Grand Unified Receipt)? Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

In-app purchase with name `test2`:

Sandbox receipt-data (generated on 13 Nov 2018, still working):

```
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
```

Apple validiation response:

```
{
    "receipt": {
        "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox",
        "adam_id": 0,
        "app_item_id": 0,
        "bundle_id": "com.belive.app.ios",
        "application_version": "3",
        "download_id": 0,
        "version_external_identifier": 0,
        "receipt_creation_date": "2018-11-13 16:46:31 Etc/GMT",
        "receipt_creation_date_ms": "1542127591000",
        "receipt_creation_date_pst": "2018-11-13 08:46:31 America/Los_Angeles",
        "request_date": "2018-11-13 17:10:31 Etc/GMT",
        "request_date_ms": "1542129031280",
        "request_date_pst": "2018-11-13 09:10:31 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1375340400000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_application_version": "1.0",
        "in_app": [{
            "quantity": "1",
            "product_id": "test2",
            "transaction_id": "1000000472106082",
            "original_transaction_id": "1000000472106082",
            "purchase_date": "2018-11-13 16:46:31 Etc/GMT",
            "purchase_date_ms": "1542127591000",
            "purchase_date_pst": "2018-11-13 08:46:31 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_purchase_date": "2018-11-13 16:46:31 Etc/GMT",
            "original_purchase_date_ms": "1542127591000",
            "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-11-13 08:46:31 America/Los_Angeles",
            "is_trial_period": "false"
        }]
    },
    "status": 0,
    "environment": "Sandbox"
}
```

URL for validation:
https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Validation request JSON body:

```
{ "receipt-data": "_paste_your_receipt-data_here_" }
```

Validation Apple Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Validation in Postman:

[image: Postman validation]

Itunes Connect In-App Purchases page:

[image: Itunes Connect In-App Purchases page]

Comment: did Apple return JSON properties with low dashes and actually expects you to send you a JSON property with a dash in it? tHinK difF3r3nT

Answer (score 28):

Sandbox receipt-data:

```
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
```

Comment: Should be declared as an answer

Comment: Encoded using Postman, and it give the right records, use this as a template to debug